# How to install php 5.6 on Ubuntu 20.04 beta

Tags: ubuntu, php-5.6

have recently installed 20.04 beta on my Laptop. I need to install php 5.6. I have googled a lot regarding it, but all are suggesting to install Via Ondrej Suri PPA. I have done that but it is giving error that 'unable to locate package php5.6'. I have checked their repository and found that they have support for 19.10 version but not for 20.04.

I have tried to find other methods but unable to find any. I am a noob on linux.

Please suggest an alternate way. I badly need this.

Answer (score 11):

You need to configure repository on your system.

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

Then update repo

```
sudo apt update
```

Once the update complete, you can install any version from 5.6 to 7.4

```
sudo apt install -y php5.6
```

Or

```
sudo apt install -y php7.4
```

Answer (score 2):

[Docker](https://www.docker.com/) is your friend.

Alternatively you could use [phpbrew](https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew).

After some time it might be that someone releases pre-built packages for PHP 5.6 but apparently that's not yet (and may never be, so don't count on it).